# SetWindowsHookEx, execute code while mouse button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, button, callback, mouse

So I made a global hotkey using `SetWindowsHookEx()`. What I want it to do is while I press the right mouse button it should execute some code again and again. The problem is that if I press the right mouse button it only executes it once.

This is my callback function:

```
private static IntPtr ButtonHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Right mouse button was clicked \n");
            }

            else if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                _m.rtbLog.AppendText("Left mouse button was clicked \n");
            }




        }

        return CallNextHookEx(MainWindow._hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Comment: Running code repeatedly requires a loop or a Timer.  Surely a timer is what you are looking for given how often a loop can loop when it needs to be started and stopped by a human finger.  Start the timer on the mousedown, stop it on the mouseup notification.  The timer is generally accurate to ~16 milliseconds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't exactly judge what's your intention, but guess you need to combine the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_RBUTTONUP` to achieve what you want. While `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, start a loop to do something, while `WM_RBUTTONUP`, stop doing.

```
private static IntPtr ButtonHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{

    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            Start();
        }

        else if (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_RBUTTONUP)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(MainWindow._hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

private static void Satrt()
{
    _toStop = false;

    while (true)
    {
        if (_toStop)
        {
            _toStop = false;
            return;
        }

        DoTask();
    }
}

private static void Stop()
{
    _toStop = true;
}

private static void DoTask()
{
    // do something
}

private static bool _toStop;
```

Comment: Yeah I managed to solve it with a timer. When the right button is down I started the timer, when it was up again I stopped it.